# Taking care of 'splash' onto adjacent frequencies

Tags: fft, filters, software-defined-radio

I have a system that should identify activity on a frequency (say in a 5kHz range), and report the frequency.  I have a problem with this system - the signal strength is sometimes wider than 5kHz, or strong enough that it bleeds over into adjacent FFT bins.  My system then recognizes (erroneously) activity in these adjacent bins / frequencies.

I am sampling at about 2MHz, I am not filtering the output (as I understand it the filtering would only control what goes into the 2MHz area, not each FFT bin).

Question: is there a way to control / detect this sort of thing, so that I know where the center frequency of activity is, and ignore the bleed into adjacent bins?

Comment: What if you look for the strongest peak close to 5kHz in your DFT, then do some sort of interpolation using the neighboring bins to estimate the center frequency?

Comment: If you just need to detect a single frequency, why use the DFT and not simply a band pass filter?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Actually I am doing this for several frequencies throughout the band, at once